# BigQuery howto load data from local file as content

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have a requirement where in I will receive file content which I need to load to BigQuery tables. Standard [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#node.js) shows how to load data from local file but I don't see any variant of the load method which accepts file content as string rather than a file path. Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/table.ts#L2055) and [official documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#load) load function loads data only from a local file or Storage File. Allowed options are:

- AVRO,
- CSV,
- JSON,
- ORC,
- PARQUET

The load job is created and it will run your data load asynchronously. If you would like instantaneous access to your data, insert it using [Table insert](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#insert) function, where you need to provide the rows to insert into the table:

```
// Insert a single row
table.insert({
  INSTNM: 'Motion Picture Institute of Michigan',
  CITY: 'Troy',
  STABBR: 'MI'
}, insertHandler);
```

If you want to load i.e. CSV file, firstly you need to [save data to a CSV in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227107/write-to-a-csv-in-node-js) manually. Then, load it as a single column CSV using `load()` method. That will load the whole string as a single column.

Additionally, what I can recommend you is to use Dataflow templates, i.e. [Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery), that read text files stored in Cloud Storage, transform them using a JavaScript User Defined Function (UDF), and output the result to BigQuery. But your data to load needs to be stored in Cloud Storage.